# Creating a portfolio project for Lucky Shrub

Tags: portfolio

Based in Tuscon, Arizona, Lucky Shrub is a medium-sized garden design firm that specializes in garden design and creation, maintenance and landscaping. The company also runs a small plant nursery that sells indoor and outdoor plants, making them a one-stop shop for clients to "transform any space into an oasis you can be proud of".

Lucky Shrub was started by a husband and wife team, Jason and Maria, who share a long-time love for plants. Jason is the garden architect. He creates and oversees all designs while managing his team of landscapers. Maria manages all the marketing for the company and oversees the nursery. make a portfolio project by using HTML and CSS . Visual layout

Semantic structure

CSS layout

CSS styling

CSS effects

Creating a portfolio project for Lucky Shrub by using index.html (Semantic Structure)and styles.css (CSS Styling and Layout)